# Return from method when validation fails

Tags: java

I want to write validation for all fields of a Java bean.

My method for blank validation is

```
private static boolean isBlank(String value) {
     return value.equalsIgnoreCase("")?true:false;
}
```

I am passing all properties of bean to the isBlank() method, and want to get out of this method when any property is blank. like this-

```
public static boolean isValid(User user) {
isBlank(user.getPersonId())?return false:{I want to stay here and check next};
isBlank(user.getEmployeeNumber());
isBlank(user.getFullName());
.
.
}
```

How can I achieve this in minimum possible code.

Comment: For starters, your `isBlank()` could just be `return value.isEmpty()`.

Comment: Can any of the fields be null? Then it might be safe to indeed use some sort of method to check both null or empty.

Comment: Read - http://www.cs.umd.edu/~clin/MoreJava/ControlFlow/nested-if.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need the `isBlank(String value)`, try this:

```
public static boolean isValid(User user){
return !(user.getPersonId().isEmpty()
    || user.getEmployeeNumber.isEmpty()
    || user.getFullName().isEmpty());
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You could use Apache `commons-lang` in your project and add this static import:

```
import static org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils.isNotEmpty;
```

Then your code can be like this:

```
public static boolean isValid(User user) {
    return isNotEmpty(user.getPersonId()) && isNotEmpty(user.getEmployeeNumber()) && isNotEmpty(user.getFullName());
}
```

Apache Commons Lang can be downloaded [here](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/download_lang.cgi) - just make sure to add it as a library to your project so that you can use the class named `StringUtils`.

Answer (score 0):

Using your code:

```
public static boolean isValid(User user) {
  if (isBlank(user.getPersonId())) return false;
  if (isBlank(user.getEmployeeNumber())) return false;
  if (isBlank(user.getFullName())) return false;
.
.
  return true;
}
```

Alternatively:

```
public static boolean isValid(User user) {
  if (isBlank(user.getPersonId()) ||
      isBlank(user.getEmployeeNumber()) ||
      isBlank(user.getFullName())) return false;
  return true;
}
```

If you want avoid to write all that code you can use reflection in order to dynamically discover the class field. If you're using bean paradigm you can use the [Introspector](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/beans/Introspector.html) class. [Here](http://v1.dione.zcu.cz/java/docs/tutorial/javabeans/introspection/index.html) a tutorial (I can't find the one on Oracle site).

Answer (score -1):

Ideal way of doing the same is using Reflection. This way you dont need to call explicily on each variable and if any variable is deleted or added you are not tightly coupled to the same.

Using reflection , loop on all the available variables and invoke isBlank from a try catch block.

```
private static boolean isBlank(String value) {
      boolean flag = value.equalsIgnoreCase(""); 
      if(flag){
        throw new Exception(e);
     }
retrun flag;

}
```

Comment: @EJP Sorry word ideal hurt your sentiments. The solution I gave will work perfectly fine.